Ambulance drivers who are junkies
A guy starts working as an ambulance driver, and is paired to an experienced ambulance driver, who starts corrupting him and getting him into drugs.
There is a very distinctive scene at the end of the movie - the senior ambulance driver is shot through the palm of his hand - he was trying to buy/sell drugs, but was somehow cheating - either he was selling aspirin saying it's drugs, or he was buying but driving off before giving any money.
There is another scene - they are at a drug addicts' den, and one of the other drug addicts suddenly suffers from an overdose. The junior ambulance driver wants to take him into the ambulance they've parked nearby, but the senior ambulance driver dissuades him, saying they would be fired, so they escape instead.
I don't really remember much more than that.
I watched the movie on TV, 10-15 years ago. I think it was a low-budget movie.

What language was it in?  Which country was it set it?

The language was English, it was an American movie I think.

I just found the movie by searching on IMDB. It's definitely this one - Broken Vessels (1998):

A young Pennsylvania man moves to Los Angeles to begin work for an ambulance service. There he is teamed with a supremely confident vet who seemingly has gone through a large number of partners. Initially the novice is awed by the more experienced man's capabilities to deal with the high pressure situations they encounter. However, gradually he discovers that all is not as it seems. While the vet is ice on the surface, he actually gets through the ordeals by heavy drug use and avoids commitments. Soon the younger man finds himself pulled into the same world and has to decide what direction he wants to take.

I searched for both 'ambulance' and 'drugs' using Google's site search feature.

Could it be Bringing out the Dead?

Frank Pierce is a paramedic working Gotham's Hell's Kitchen. He's become burned out and haunted by visions of the people he's tried to save.


Oops, I had forgotten to accept it. But this movie you're linking seems nice, too.

Np. This was just what came to mind, i dont remember it as great, but worth a watch. Just joined my "Must watch again list"
